# Vscode - Space in Terminal after run python files

Tags: python, terminal

how can i fix this and what's causing the problem? i was using Code Runner but i thought it was the problem so i disabled but this keep happens.

[run1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7MAM.png)

[run2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxoDu.png)

[run3 after clear terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVE6y.png)

Comment: please convert all pics to code in the question. as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . it will help others resolve the problem much quicker for you.